# Linearly interpolating values in a large R data frame grouped by date using tidyverse

Tags: r, interpolation, tidyr

I am attempting to interpolate (linearly or by other methods) between values in an R data frame. The values are grouped by a date_index in a very large dataframe, and the interpolation is between the values on a daily basis based on the f_dates. The number of f_dates changes so the interpolation, presumably,  needs to be grouped for each date_index and then ungrouped into a larger data frame? See example below.

My attempt at the code is as follows, but I can't seem to get the grouping and interpolation to work.

```
df <- data.frame("date_index"=c("20230104", "20230104", "20230104", "20230106",  "20230106", "20230106"),
"f_date"=c("20230201", "20230203", "20230210", "20230201", "20230203", "20230210"),
                 "value" = c(1.50, 2.00, 3.25, 4.00, 3.00, 2.50))  %>% 
  mutate(date_index=ymd(date_index), f_date=ymd(f_date))

df %>% 
  group_by(date_index) %>% 
  arrange(f_date)

date_first <- first(df$f_date)
date_last <- last(df$f_date)

ApproxFun <- approxfun(x = df$f_date, y = df$value)

date_seq <- seq.Date(ymd(date_first), ymd(date_last), by = 1)

LinearFit <- ApproxFun(date_seq)

# the interpolated dataframe
dfi <- data.frame(f_date = date_seq,  value = LinearFit)
```

The output I was looking for should be as follows:

```
date_index  f_date  value
2023-01-04  2023-02-01  1.50
2023-01-04  2023-02-02  1.75
2023-01-04  2023-02-03  2.00
2023-01-04  2023-02-04  2.18
2023-01-04  2023-02-05  2.36
2023-01-04  2023-02-06  2.54
2023-01-04  2023-02-07  2.71
2023-01-04  2023-02-08  2.89
2023-01-04  2023-02-09  3.07
2023-01-04  2023-02-10  3.25
2023-01-06  2023-02-01  4.00
2023-01-06  2023-02-02  3.50
2023-01-06  2023-02-03  3.00
2023-01-06  2023-02-04  2.93
2023-01-06  2023-02-05  2.86
2023-01-06  2023-02-06  2.79
2023-01-06  2023-02-07  2.71
2023-01-06  2023-02-08  2.64
2023-01-06  2023-02-09  2.57
2023-01-06  2023-02-10  2.50
```

Comment: Thank-you. Very handy function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner using the `tidyr::complete()` function and the `approx()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(date_index) %>% 
   complete(f_date=full_seq(f_date, 1)) %>% 
   mutate(value=approx(f_date[!is.na(.$value)], y=value[!is.na(.$value)], xout=f_date, method = "linear")$y)

# A tibble: 20 × 3
# Groups:   date_index [2]
  date_index f_date     value
      <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 2023-01-04 2023-02-01  1.5 
2 2023-01-04 2023-02-02  1.75
3 2023-01-04 2023-02-03  2   
4 2023-01-04 2023-02-04  2.18
5 2023-01-04 2023-02-05  2.36
6 2023-01-04 2023-02-06  2.54
7 2023-01-04 2023-02-07  2.71
8 2023-01-04 2023-02-08  2.89
9 2023-01-04 2023-02-09  3.07
10 2023-01-04 2023-02-10  3.25
11 2023-01-06 2023-02-01  4   
12 2023-01-06 2023-02-02  3.5 
13 2023-01-06 2023-02-03  3   
14 2023-01-06 2023-02-04  2.93
15 2023-01-06 2023-02-05  2.86
16 2023-01-06 2023-02-06  2.79
17 2023-01-06 2023-02-07  2.71
18 2023-01-06 2023-02-08  2.64
19 2023-01-06 2023-02-09  2.57
20 2023-01-06 2023-02-10  2.5
```

The complete function is a handy to have and will fill-in the missing values in a given sequence, in this case in 1 day intervals.
Once the missing dates are define, then simply use the approx function to interpolate for the NA values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to make this happen with an "out-of-the-box" function, though I don't doubt that it's possible.  First, let's make the data then I'll explain the solution.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame("date_index"=c("20230104", "20230104", "20230104", "20230106",  "20230106", "20230106"),
                 "f_date"=c("20230201", "20230203", "20230210", "20230201", "20230203", "20230210"),
                 "value" = c(1.50, 2.00, 3.25, 4.00, 3.00, 2.50))  %>% 
  mutate(date_index=ymd(date_index), f_date=ymd(f_date))
```

I wrote a function that does an interpolation with a piecewise-linear regression model that is just identified - it has as many parameters as there are non-missing values of the `value` variable.  It then uses that model to generate predictions using the observed values of `value` as knots.

```r
interp_fun <- function(x,y){
  pwl <- function(x, k)sapply(k, function(K)ifelse(x >= K, x-K, 0))
  w <- which(!is.na(y))
  if(length(w) > 2){
    w <- w[-c(1, length(w))]
    kts <- x[w]
    mod <- lm(y ~ x + pwl(x, kts), na.action=na.exclude)
    ifelse(is.na(y), predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), y)
  }else{
    mod <- lm(y ~ x, na.action=na.exclude)
    ifelse(is.na(y), predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), y)
  }
}
```

With the interpolation function in hand, you can group the data by `date_index`, then generate a new sequence of dates from the minimum to the maximum of `f_date` and then merge that back into the original data. You can group by `date_index` and then apply the interpolation function to `f_date` and `value`.  The result appears as though it's the one you want.  This should work regardless of how many "interior" observed values you have between the observed endpoints.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(date_index) %>% 
  arrange(f_date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  reframe(f_date = seq(from = min(f_date), 
                       to = max(f_date), 
                       by = "1 day")) %>% 
  left_join(df) %>%
  group_by(date_index) %>% 
  mutate(value = interp_fun(f_date, value))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(date_index, f_date)`
#> # A tibble: 20 × 3
#> # Groups:   date_index [2]
#>    date_index f_date     value
#>    <date>     <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 2023-01-04 2023-02-01  1.5 
#>  2 2023-01-04 2023-02-02  1.75
#>  3 2023-01-04 2023-02-03  2   
#>  4 2023-01-04 2023-02-04  2.18
#>  5 2023-01-04 2023-02-05  2.36
#>  6 2023-01-04 2023-02-06  2.54
#>  7 2023-01-04 2023-02-07  2.71
#>  8 2023-01-04 2023-02-08  2.89
#>  9 2023-01-04 2023-02-09  3.07
#> 10 2023-01-04 2023-02-10  3.25
#> 11 2023-01-06 2023-02-01  4   
#> 12 2023-01-06 2023-02-02  3.50
#> 13 2023-01-06 2023-02-03  3   
#> 14 2023-01-06 2023-02-04  2.93
#> 15 2023-01-06 2023-02-05  2.86
#> 16 2023-01-06 2023-02-06  2.79
#> 17 2023-01-06 2023-02-07  2.71
#> 18 2023-01-06 2023-02-08  2.64
#> 19 2023-01-06 2023-02-09  2.57
#> 20 2023-01-06 2023-02-10  2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it using `summarise` and `unnest`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
interpolator <- function(x, y) {
  date_first <- first(x)
  date_last <- last(x)
  interpolant <- approxfun(x = x, y = y)
  date_seq <- seq.Date(ymd(date_first), ymd(date_last), by = 1)
  tibble(
    f_date = date_seq, value = interpolant(date_seq)
  )
}

df <- data.frame("date_index"=c("20230104", "20230104", "20230104", "20230106",  "20230106", "20230106"),
                 "f_date"=c("20230201", "20230203", "20230210", "20230201", "20230203", "20230210"),
                 "value" = c(1.50, 2.00, 3.25, 4.00, 3.00, 2.50))  %>% 
  mutate(date_index=ymd(date_index), f_date=ymd(f_date))

df %>% 
  group_by(date_index) %>% 
  arrange(f_date) %>% 
  summarise(
    tmp = list(interpolator(f_date, value))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tmp)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 3
#>    date_index f_date     value
#>    <date>     <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 2023-01-04 2023-02-01  1.5 
#>  2 2023-01-04 2023-02-02  1.75
#>  3 2023-01-04 2023-02-03  2   
#>  4 2023-01-04 2023-02-04  2.18
#>  5 2023-01-04 2023-02-05  2.36
#>  6 2023-01-04 2023-02-06  2.54
#>  7 2023-01-04 2023-02-07  2.71
#>  8 2023-01-04 2023-02-08  2.89
#>  9 2023-01-04 2023-02-09  3.07
#> 10 2023-01-04 2023-02-10  3.25
#> 11 2023-01-06 2023-02-01  4   
#> 12 2023-01-06 2023-02-02  3.5 
#> 13 2023-01-06 2023-02-03  3   
#> 14 2023-01-06 2023-02-04  2.93
#> 15 2023-01-06 2023-02-05  2.86
#> 16 2023-01-06 2023-02-06  2.79
#> 17 2023-01-06 2023-02-07  2.71
#> 18 2023-01-06 2023-02-08  2.64
#> 19 2023-01-06 2023-02-09  2.57
#> 20 2023-01-06 2023-02-10  2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>